# How do I parse JSON in Racket?

Tags: json, parsing, racket

I can't seem to figure out the {[documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html)}, there aren't really any examples of parsing some simple JSON data, so I was wondering if anyone here could give me some examples to get started.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a very simple example:

```lisp
(require json)
(define x (string->jsexpr "{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"bar\": \"baz\"}"))
(for (((key val) (in-hash x)))
  (printf "~a = ~a~%" key val))
```

Here's how you can use it with a JSON-based API:

```lisp
(require net/http-client json)
(define-values (status header response)
  (http-sendrecv "httpbin.org" "/ip" #:ssl? 'tls))
(define data (read-json response))
(printf "My IP address is ~a~%" (hash-ref data 'origin))
```

At the OP's request, here's how you can create a JSON value from a structure type:

```lisp
(require json)
(struct person (first-name last-name age country))
(define (person->jsexpr p)
  (hasheq 'first-name (person-first-name p)
          'last-name (person-last-name p)
          'age (person-age p)
          'country (person-country p)))
(define cky (person "Chris" "Jester-Young" 33 "New Zealand"))
(jsexpr->string (person->jsexpr cky))
```

Comment: can you add an example for going back again?

Comment: Sure, just use `(jsexpr->string x)` for the example above.

Comment: no I mean making data from scratch, and then turning it into a json string, I'm fairly new to racket, so bare with me

Comment: What kind of data do you want to create JSON of? I want to create a useful example.

Comment: could you do a simple person data thing? you know with a first name, last name, age, and country or something, that'd be great

Comment: Okay, here we go, added how to create JSON from a structure type. Enjoy!

Comment: Nice answer! It would be great if you submitted a pull request that adds examples like these to the docs. :)

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa Thanks! I don't currently see any examples in the `json` module documentation, where would these go?